# How do I move file assets from src into bin at compile time in FDT5

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, fdt

Flash Builder has a nice feature that will allow you to have it move files such as images, fonts, xml files and so forth into the bin-debug directory an compile time. The reason for doing this would be to mock up some data or test pulling in assets dynamically but having them in source directory so you can version control the assets during development. Typically we don't add the bin directory to version control so being able to have the IDE move files over to bin for you is very helpful if you are on a large team.

Is there a feature within FDT5 that will do this like Flash Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not, but it sounds cool. Could you provide a screenshot of what looks like in FB (I'll add it to JIRA as a feature request).

[Here is the feature request](http://bugs.powerflasher.com/jira/browse/FDT-2558).

The thing to do would be to write a simple Ant script that moves your files. 
([Learn more about FDT Ant scripts](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/FDT_Ant_Tasks))

Here is a sample snippet we use on the FDT team that deletes an old file and puts in fresh ones:

```
    <target name="move zip to core plugin">
        <delete file="${basedir}/../../com.powerflasher.fdt.core/src/com/powerflasher/fdt/internal/core/preferences/projectTemplate/projectTemplates.zip">
        </delete>
        <copy todir="${basedir}/../../com.powerflasher.fdt.core/src/com/powerflasher/fdt/internal/core/preferences/projectTemplate/" file="${basedir}/../projectTemplates.zip" />
    </target>
```

Put it here:

[image]

Comment: There is no view of this 'feature'. FlashBuilder just copies whatever files are on your source path to the 'bin' folder. Which means your configuration files have to be in the 'src' folder for this to work. I really don't like that; I prefer an ANT script any time (you _can_ combine IDE build and ANT script in FB, but it's a hard feature to find). Perhaps an IDE view where you could select files to publish along with the app might be helpfull.

Comment: Right...no view per se but there is a checkbox that does this. Check out the JIRA ticket I link to.